# Loop through PHP array with Jquery event handlers

Tags: php, jquery, html

**Background:**
I have an HTML form with an internal PHP processing script that takes checkbox categories and converts them into a string of directory locations of images that is passed into a glob() function.

**Situation:**
I have an array of image src paths from glob function
*example*

```
<?php
  $images //ARRAY OF IMG SRC PATHS
?>
```

I want to attach click and keyboard events to loop through $images array
*example*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#img_viewer').click(function(){
    //LOOP THROUGH $images array on click one at a time
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't think to separate this php logic and call it using jquery ajax?

Comment: When I set the form action to an external php file, it redirects to that external page on submit and this is a Single Page Application

Comment: You should not set form action. You should call it by jquery ajax. If you want I can show you my solution with separating php logic and main and keeping single page

Comment: @Dan you can prevent the form from submitting to the php file instead use jquery ajax to handle the post request. inside a callback function you can do this function(event){event.preventDefault;}

Comment: Why don't you output the `$images` using something in PHP at that very position you wrote the comment in your JS function?

Comment: @pinoyCoder Yeah, if you have an example that would be great!

Comment: @NicoHaase Putting php tags inside my Jquery script isnt working...

Comment: How could that not work? Can you add that not working code to your question?

Comment: Wait, @Dan what are you trying to achieve here? Why are you using php variable instead of outputting your list to html as hidden or shown select or ul element?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would separate PHP logic:

**images.php**

```
<?php
    //some logic here
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

**your javascript:**

```
$(#img_viewer).click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'images.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
                //in [value] is your src of images
        });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this

```
$(#img_viewer).click(function(){
           $.ajax({
           method:'post',
           url: 'the url for the php file',
           data:{}, // you can pass any data that can used to your php file
           success:function(respose){
            // do something
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

First convert PHP array of images to Javascript array

`<?php 
$php_array   = array(//images); 
$js_array       = json_encode($php_array); 
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n"; ?>`

And set counter to

`var counter = 0;`

And then

`$(document).ready(function(){ $(document).click(function(){ console.log(javascript_array[counter]);
   counter++;});`

Comment: for json_encode don't I have to set up some kind of cookies/local storage/database? and if possible I wouldnt wanna do that unless absolutely vital

Comment: Your previous code stated that you want to loop throup PHP images array when the document is clicked

Comment: Answe: no you don't need to set such

Comment: Yeah I had just picked a random element for example and i realized document made no sense if i had an checkbox form because the code would run when people clicked that

Comment: Yes, my response is based on the first question

Comment: You can modify it to suit your needs to

Comment: please don't echo php virables to javascript directly. This just leads to nasty looking code that is hard to refractor and debug later on. Use AJAX calls to server instead

Comment: There is a reason to do Ajax Call, e.g when you want to do database search/communicate with another server